# SharePoint Designer not saving changes

Tags: development

I've developed a SharePoint WebPart but am having trouble editing it in the SharePoint Designer. My WebPart is supposed to be a thin wrapper around a DevExpress Chart which exposes all the settings in SharePoint designer. My code looks like this (note that the Chart.acsx.g.cs has a protected member chartControl:

```
  [ControlBuilder(typeof(ChartControlBuilder))]
public partial class Chart : Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart, IChartView, IWebEditable
{
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public WebChartControl ChartControl
    {
        get { return this.chartControl; }
        set { this.chartControl = value; }
    }

    protected override void AddParsedSubObject(object obj)
    {
        if (obj != null)
            Trace.WriteLine(obj.GetType());

        base.AddParsedSubObject(obj);
    }
```

Where the ChartControlBuilder does the following:

```
 public class ChartControlBuilder : ControlBuilder
{
    public override Type GetChildControlType(string tagName, System.Collections.IDictionary attribs)
    {
        if (tagName == "ChartControl")
            return typeof(WebChartControl);

        Type type = base.GetChildControlType(tagName, attribs);
        return type;
    }
}
```

This gives me the following output in SharePoint Designer... I decided to make a simple change, modifying the width of the Width of the ChartControl:

```
<WpNs0:Chart runat="server" AllowEdit="True" AllowConnect="True" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" Title="Chart" ConnectionString="Data Source=esx-sharepoint;Initial Catalog=Test;Uid=User1;Pwd=MyPassword;" Dir="Default" IsIncluded="True" IsVisible="True" CatalogIconImageUrl="/_layouts/images/WebParts/ChartIcon.png" AllowMinimize="True" AllowHide="True" ExportControlledProperties="True" ZoneID="LeftColumn" ID="g_5ea391cf_215a_48bc_bd24_267d8ef5d9d0" FrameState="Normal" SelectQuery="select top 20        TH.TH_TNM_Threat_Name,        TH.TH_TSS_Threat_SOCScore AS [SOC Score] from lTH_parent_TH_to T1 inner join lTH_Threat THP on THP.TH_ID=T1.TH_ID_parent inner join lTH_Threat TH on TH.TH_ID=T1.TH_ID_to where        THP.TH_TNM_Threat_Name='Global Threat' order by TH.TH_TSS_Threat_SOCScore DESC" ExportMode="All" AllowRemove="True" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" DetailLink="" HelpLink="" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." PartImageSmall="/_layouts/images/WebParts/ChartIcon.png" TitleIconImageUrl="/_layouts/images/WebParts/ChartIcon.png" HelpMode="Modeless" FrameType="Default" AllowZoneChange="True" PartOrder="2" Description="A web part used to display a Chart" PartImageLarge="/_layouts/images/WebParts/ChartIcon.png" IsIncludedFilter="" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{5EA391CF-215A-48BC-BD24-267D8EF5D9D0}" WebPart="true" Height="" Width="">
<ChartControl Width="300px" Height="200px" Theme="BlackGlass" EnableTheming="True" ID="chartControl"><DiagramSerializable>
<cc1:XYDiagram>
<AxisX VisibleInPanesSerializable="-1">
<Range SideMarginsEnabled="True"></Range>
</AxisX>

<AxisY VisibleInPanesSerializable="-1">
<Range SideMarginsEnabled="True"></Range>
</AxisY>
</cc1:XYDiagram>
</DiagramSerializable>

<FillStyle><OptionsSerializable>
<cc1:SolidFillOptions></cc1:SolidFillOptions>
</OptionsSerializable>
</FillStyle>
<SeriesSerializable>
<cc1:Series Name="Series 1"><ViewSerializable>
<cc1:SideBySideBarSeriesView></cc1:SideBySideBarSeriesView>
</ViewSerializable>
<LabelSerializable>
<cc1:SideBySideBarSeriesLabel LineVisible="True">
<FillStyle><OptionsSerializable>
<cc1:SolidFillOptions></cc1:SolidFillOptions>
</OptionsSerializable>
</FillStyle>
<PointOptionsSerializable>
<cc1:PointOptions></cc1:PointOptions>
</PointOptionsSerializable>
</cc1:SideBySideBarSeriesLabel>
</LabelSerializable>
<LegendPointOptionsSerializable>
<cc1:PointOptions></cc1:PointOptions>
</LegendPointOptionsSerializable>
</cc1:Series>
</SeriesSerializable>

<SeriesTemplate><ViewSerializable>
<cc1:SideBySideBarSeriesView></cc1:SideBySideBarSeriesView>
</ViewSerializable>
<LabelSerializable>
<cc1:SideBySideBarSeriesLabel LineVisible="True">
<FillStyle><OptionsSerializable>
<cc1:SolidFillOptions></cc1:SolidFillOptions>
</OptionsSerializable>
</FillStyle>
<PointOptionsSerializable>
<cc1:PointOptions></cc1:PointOptions>
</PointOptionsSerializable>
</cc1:SideBySideBarSeriesLabel>
</LabelSerializable>
<LegendPointOptionsSerializable>
<cc1:PointOptions></cc1:PointOptions>
</LegendPointOptionsSerializable>
</SeriesTemplate>

<CrosshairOptions><CommonLabelPositionSerializable>
<cc1:CrosshairMousePosition></cc1:CrosshairMousePosition>
</CommonLabelPositionSerializable>
</CrosshairOptions>

<ToolTipOptions><ToolTipPositionSerializable>
<cc1:ToolTipMousePosition></cc1:ToolTipMousePosition>
</ToolTipPositionSerializable>
</ToolTipOptions>
</ChartControl>
</WpNs0:Chart>
```

If I modify the width of the ChartControl I notice that AddParsedSubObject gets called a number of times and it seems to have a WebChartControl (width 800px yay!) and another one (which is the this.chartControl instance with a width if 300px). I don't understand why I've got these 2 instances being added to this.Controls (this is what the AddParsedSubObject does in the base) in the first place.

When I preview the page from SharePoint designer, or the web I notice that there is now only 1 WebChartControl added in AddParsedSubObject with the 300px default width. I don't understand what's happening, could someone help get me going in the right direction? Things I've looked at so far:

- Ensuring I'm checking files in after changing them in SharePoint Designer.
- Editing files in Advanced Mode.
- I searched for but couldn't find the ddwrt:ghost="hide" string in the ChartTest.aspx page in SharePoint Designer.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**

I've tried adding another property onto the Chart (SelectQuery) which is included in the ASPX output in the designer as an Attribute on my webpart. I've noticed that I am successfully able to modify that attribute and the chart will update on a refresh or preview. It only seems to be if I modify the child control that things don't  update correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would help, but it may be another solution for you to try.
save your webpart and install it in SharePoint. Then in SP designer create a web part zone with a table in it. Add your webpart inside of the table from SP designer. This should constrict the WP to the size of the table.

Comment: I've used size as a trivial example, in reality there are a whole range of properties I may wish to change (palette, connection string, axis label position etc. etc). Your answer may workaround the particular issue I have here in my example but is not the sort of answer I'm after.